# Android FrameLayout and dynamic clipping

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I have a FrameLayout that contains 2 other FrameLayouts.  I want one of the internal FrameLayouts to never clip and I want the other internal FrameLayout (containing an ImageView that is centered in the FrameLayout) to clip or not clip based on user actions.  The case that I am most interested in is when the Image is larger then the FrameLayout that contains it.

If I do setClipChildren(false) or setClipChildren(true) on the containing layout, then everything clips or not based on the value.

If I do setClipChildren(false) on the containing FrameLayout and setClipChildren(true) on the internal FrameLayout, then the ImageView added to the internal FrameLayout is not clipped.  Does the clip children state from the parent layout propagate to the child layouts?

I have tried CLIP_HORIZONTAL, CLIP_VERTICAL as well as FILL_HORIZONTAL, FILL_VERTICAL in the internal FrameLayout.

I am trying to avoid setClipBounds() because the size can change and I was hoping that the FrameLayout would figure out the correct size based on Gravity.CENTER and the clip children state.  Is there a way to get Android to do the clipping for me?  Otherwise, I have to calculate the size, shift the margins and set the clip bounds.  It seems like something that Android should already handle.

[image: Diagram]

FrameLayout 1 should never clip.  FrameLayout 2 should clip or not clip the ImageView based on some other information available to the application.

The following is the layout xml and code for the test app:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/FrameLayoutMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayoutClip"
    android:layout_width="84dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxClipMain"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Clip - Main" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxClipChild"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Clip - Child" />

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayoutText"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:text="Large Text to fill up a text view so that we can test how clipping occurs with TextViews and FrameLayouts.  It looks like this will be long enough."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayoutImage"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="600dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200px"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/test_image" />
</FrameLayout>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private CheckBox _mainCheckBox = null;
private CheckBox _childCheckBox = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewGroup tempViewGroup = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.FrameLayoutMain);
    tempViewGroup.setClipChildren(false);
    tempViewGroup = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.FrameLayoutClip);
    tempViewGroup.setClipChildren(false);

    _mainCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxClipMain);
    _mainCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    _mainCheckBox.setChecked(false);

    _childCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxClipChild);
    _childCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    _childCheckBox.setChecked(false);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1)
{
  ViewGroup mainViewGroup = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.FrameLayoutMain);
  if (arg0 == _childCheckBox)
  {
     ViewGroup tempViewGroup = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.FrameLayoutText);
     Log.d(TAG, "child onCheckChanged is " + arg1);
     tempViewGroup.setClipChildren(arg1);
     tempViewGroup = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.FrameLayoutImage);
     tempViewGroup.setClipChildren(arg1);
  }
  else if (arg0 == _mainCheckBox)
  {
     Log.d(TAG, "main onCheckChanged is " + arg1);
     mainViewGroup.setClipChildren(arg1);
  }
  mainViewGroup.invalidate();
}

}
```

Comment: post an image showing what you want to achieve

Comment: I have written a test app to explore this concept.  It appears that Android will not do what I want with just setClipChildren.  The setClipChildren from the top most layout overrides the values for all ViewGroups.  Even if the child ViewGroup's setClipChildren is called after the top most layout's setClipChildren.

Comment: I also noticed that WRAP_CONTENT will limit a child view to the size of the parent ViewGroup that contains it.  In order for setClipChildren(false) to show what I want, I have to specify an actual width and height for the child's LayoutParams.

Comment: this what i got from one of google dev https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-developers/dZ0Yxjz3v7o